# Jenkins build failing with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/tasks/SimpleBuildStep

Tags: java, jenkins, build, classnotfoundexception

After the build operation finished the job  fails with the following error. We had installed the naginator plugin then removed it. From that point this is happening. I tried reinstalling the plugin even then it is happening.

```
FATAL: jenkins/tasks/SimpleBuildStep
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/tasks/SimpleBuildStep
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1138)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2.defineClassFromData(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:755)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1309)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1365)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1325)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at jenkins.ClassLoaderReflectionToolkit.invoke(ClassLoaderReflectionToolkit.java:44)
    at jenkins.ClassLoaderReflectionToolkit._findClass(ClassLoaderReflectionToolkit.java:86)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$DependencyClassLoader.findClass(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findBaseClass(AntClassLoader.java:1397)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1074)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.hasHudsonTasksMailer(GitChangeSet.java:296)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.findOrCreateUser(GitChangeSet.java:274)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.getAuthor(GitChangeSet.java:329)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:352)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:689)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1757)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1375)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1325)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1078)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: How are you installing Jenkins, which OS are you using and which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04. Installed via apt-get . Java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)

Comment: Is there a solution for this question?

Answer (score -3):

Updating Jenkins to the latest version sort of fixed the issue

```
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Comment: Sort of? Can you elaborate please?